# How to properly configure SQS without using SNS topics in MassTransit?

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, masstransit

I'm having some issues configuring MassTransit with SQS. My goal is to have N consumers which create N queues and each of them accept a different message type. Since I always have a 1 to 1 consumer to message mapping, I'm not interested in having any sort of fan-out behaviour. So publishing a message of type T should publish it directly to that queue. How exactly would I configure that? This is what I have so far:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
    x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("aws", h =>
        {
            h.AccessKey(mtSettings.AccessKey);
            h.SecretKey(mtSettings.SecretKey);

            h.Scope($"{mtSettings.Environment}", true);
            var sqsConfig = new AmazonSQSConfig() { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(mtSettings.Region) };
            h.Config(sqsConfig);

            var snsConfig = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig()
                    { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(mtSettings.Region) };
            h.Config(snsConfig);
        });
        
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new BusEnvironmentNameFormatter(mtSettings.Environment));
    });
});
```

The `BusEnvironmentNameFormatter` class overrides `KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter` and adds the environment as a prefix, and the effect is that all the queues start with 'dev', while the `h.Scope($"{mtSettings.Environment}", true)` line does the same for topics.

I've tried to get this working without configuring topics at all, but I couldn't get it working without any errors. What am I missing?

The SQS docs are a bit thin, but is at actually possible to do a `bus.Publish()` without using sns topics or are they necessary? If it's not possible, how would I use `bus.Send()` without hardcoding queue names in the call?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Publish` requires the use of topics, which in the case of SQS uses SNS.

If you want to configure the endpoints yourself, and prevent the use of topics, you'd need to:

1. Set `ConfigureConsumeTopology = false` – this prevents topics from being created and connected to the receive endpoint queue.
2. Set `PublishFaults = false` – this prevents fault topics from being created when a consumer throws an exception.
3. Don't call `Publish`, because, *obviously* that will create a topic.

If you want to somehow establish a convention for your receive endpoint names that aligns with your ability to send messages, you *could* create your own endpoint name formatter that would use message types and then use those same names to call `GetSendEndpoint` using the `queue:name` short name syntax to *Send* messages directly to those queues.